# Do I rebuild the Electron package to get customized front-end with Rocket Chat?

Tags: electron, rocket.chat

I use a self-hosted Rocket Chat installation and I use it via the Rocket Chat Electron desktop application.

I want to customize front-end of Rocket Chat by including some open PRs (https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/pull/10366).

I wonder where does the front end comes from when I use the Rocket Chat Electron app? If I modify the front end at my self-hosted installation will the changes be there when I use the service via the official unchanged Rocket Chat Electron application?

I'm new to Electron development so I don't know how exactly Electron app work and where does the front end comes from - the server side or the client desktop app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now I know that the way Rocket Chat Electron application works, it loads the actual Rocket Chat frontend from the remote Rocket Chat web application, so in order to modify the way the front-end works one has to modify the original Rocket Chat web app installation but not the Rocket Chat Electron app.